# Why event is triggered more than once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, soundmanager2

I'm trying to add an event handler for an audio Javascript plugin using the SoundManager2. This is the function that plays a song and wait for the end of the song to execute the function again:

```
    function songPlay (newSrc) {

            htmlSound.src = newSrc;
            htmlSound.load();

            thisPlayer.find( ".total-position-scrubber" ).bind( "slide", function(event, ui) {
                htmlSound.currentTime = ui.value;
            });

            var currentArtist = currentRow.find(".total-artist").text();
            var currentTitle =  currentRow.find(".total-title").text();

            thisPlayer.find(".total-playing-artist").html(currentArtist);
            thisPlayer.find(".total-playing-title").html(currentTitle);

            htmlSound.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
                var newVolume = thisPlayer.find( ".total-volume-slider" ).slider("option", "value");
                htmlSound.volume = newVolume;

                var duration = htmlSound.duration * 1000;
                var durationTime = convertMilliseconds(duration, "mm:ss");
                thisPlayer.find(".total-song-duration").html(durationTime.clock );

                var position = htmlSound.currentTime * 1000;
                var positionTime = convertMilliseconds(position, "mm:ss");
                thisPlayer.find(".total-song-position").html(positionTime.clock );

                thisPlayer.find( ".total-position-scrubber" ).slider("option", "max", duration/1000);
                thisPlayer.find( ".total-position-scrubber" ).slider("option", "value", position/1000);

            });

            htmlSound.addEventListener("ended", function() {

                        // Find next checked song

                        currentRow = currentRow.nextAll(".can-play:first");

                        // If checked song exists after current song, load it
                        if(currentRow.length > 0)
                        {
                            var newSrc = currentRow.find("[src]").attr("src");
                            songPlay(newSrc);
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            // If no checked song exists after current song, load the first checked song in playlist
                            if(thisPlayer.find(".can-play").length > 0)
                            {
                                currentRow = thisPlayer.find(".can-play:first");
                                var newSrc = currentRow.find("[src]").attr("src");
                                songPlay(newSrc);
                            }
                            // Change pause button to play button
                            else
                            {
                                thisPlayer.find(".total-play").removeClass("total-pause");  
                            }

                        }
                        // If song is playing while next button is clicked play next song
                        if(thisPlayer.find(".total-pause").length > 0)
                        {
                            htmlSound.play();

                        }

            });

            thisPlayer.find(".total-row .total-not-playing").removeClass("total-playing");
            currentRow.find(".total-not-playing").addClass("total-playing");
        }
```

The only problem is that the "ended" event is triggered more than once every time that a song finishes. After the "ended" event, the function is executed, and then the `songPlay()` function is executed again (this is the expected behavior), but then, the "ended" event is triggered again, before the song is finished, while it should wait for the end of the song. Any idea of the cause of that behavior?

**The `newSrc` variable has always the right value.**

This is the "ended" event definition in SoundManager2:

```
_html5_events = {

  // HTML5 event-name-to-handler map
  ...
  ended: _html5_event(function() {

  var t = this._t;

  _s._wD(_h5+'ended: '+t.sID);
  t._onfinish();

 }),
 ...
}
```

**Edit:**

Surprisingly, it worked just replacing the anonymous function with a declared function like this:

```
function eventListenerFunction() {

        // Find next checked song

        currentRow = currentRow.nextAll(".can-play:first");

        // If checked song exists after current song, load it
        if(currentRow.length > 0)
        {
            var newSrc = currentRow.find("[src]").attr("src");
            songPlay(newSrc);
        }

        else
        {
            // If no checked song exists after current song, load the first checked song in playlist
            if(thisPlayer.find(".can-play").length > 0)
            {
                currentRow = thisPlayer.find(".can-play:first");
                var newSrc = currentRow.find("[src]").attr("src");
                songPlay(newSrc);
            }
            // Change pause button to play button
            else
            {
                    thisPlayer.find(".total-play").removeClass("total-pause");  
            }

        }
        // If song is playing while next button is clicked play next song
        if(thisPlayer.find(".total-pause").length > 0)
        {
            htmlSound.play();

        }

});

function songPlay (newSrc) {

    htmlSound.src = newSrc;
    htmlSound.load();

    thisPlayer.find( ".total-position-scrubber" ).bind( "slide", function(event, ui) {
        htmlSound.currentTime = ui.value;
    });

    var currentArtist = currentRow.find(".total-artist").text();
    var currentTitle =  currentRow.find(".total-title").text();

    thisPlayer.find(".total-playing-artist").html(currentArtist);
    thisPlayer.find(".total-playing-title").html(currentTitle);

    htmlSound.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
        var newVolume = thisPlayer.find( ".total-volume-slider" ).slider("option", "value");
        htmlSound.volume = newVolume;

        var duration = htmlSound.duration * 1000;
        var durationTime = convertMilliseconds(duration, "mm:ss");
            thisPlayer.find(".total-song-duration").html(durationTime.clock );

        var position = htmlSound.currentTime * 1000;
        var positionTime = convertMilliseconds(position, "mm:ss");
        thisPlayer.find(".total-song-position").html(positionTime.clock );

        thisPlayer.find( ".total-position-scrubber" ).slider("option", "max", duration/1000);
        thisPlayer.find( ".total-position-scrubber" ).slider("option", "value", position/1000);

    });

    htmlSound.addEventListener("ended", eventListenerFunction)

    thisPlayer.find(".total-row .total-not-playing").removeClass("total-playing");
    currentRow.find(".total-not-playing").addClass("total-playing");
}
```

However, I guess I should use `$('body').off("ended")` after the triggered function to remove the event listener, as @Fallenreaper has suggested.

Comment: Double check all your base cases.   Since there are cases in which you call songplay inside of a listener which is applied inside of songplay, as you click you will have a circular structure which will keep applying new listeners.

Comment: @Fallenreaper - But I want to apply a new listener each time, so why not to call the function again inside the listener function?

Comment: You might want to remove the previous listener and REAPPLY, not append new listeners.  The issue is that you click and the event fires once, then click again it will fire twice, click again, fire 4 times, etc.  If you want to apply a new listener, you can, but im informing you accordingly.  You would want to override the original.  Doing this is as easy as $("item").off("functionName"); in jquery.

Comment: @Fallenreaper - If I understand well, I should give a name to the event triggered function and then remove the listener... `htmlSound.off('eventTriggeredFunction')`

Comment: You can only remove a event if there is a name for it.  So, you would want to define the function with a name, and then reassign, yes.  You got it. :)  There is also a non-jquery way, but that is unknown to me at the moment.

Comment: @Fallenreaper - `removeEventListener`. Thanks. I'll try and come back.

Comment: @Fallenreaper - It worked for me just replacing the anonymous function with a declared function. ???

Answer (score 1):

you call songplay inside of a listener, which applies it another time.... and another time and another time.

recursion.

```
>_>
```